# Odd Script Execution SSIS

Tags: ssis, dtexec

I'm probably going to word this poorly, but here goes.

I've created an SSIS Package with an email proceedure. It is *supposed* to send three emails, each one based on a SQL query.

[image: Control Flow]

The email tasks run sequentially, as part of the reporting requirement (An automated run is required daily, but sometimes one of the three emails needs to be sent manually. In those cases the other two Data Flow Tasks are disabled)

Heres where things get fishy. I can run the task from the editor, and no issues arise. Results: 3 emails, limited latency. These are relatively small queries (~50k records). When the task is run from Windows Task Scheduler, I get two of the three emails (notably the first two in the sequence), and quite a bit of latency (~10 minutes total execution, ~ 3 minutes between emails.) Latency isn't concerning me, but the missing email is.

The task is set to expire if it runs longer than 12 hours, so timeout is unlikely the cause. I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure this out!

Note: to make things more interesting, I recompiled the script executing all three email (script) tasks in one data flow task. Same behaviour there, with a very interesting twist. Every time I complied the bianries with three email tasks *I got a two emails*

Example:

Compile 1 -> Load into Windows Task Scheduler

Result -> Lab & IT email

Compile 2-> Load into Windows Task Scheduler

Result -> Base & IT email

The heck?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it will be hard to diagnose what is happening. Is there a reason you aren't using the native send mail task?

Comment: @bilinkc Yes. The reporting itself has several math and future dates requirements that require a bit of extra horsepower. In the native send mail handles these cases im currently unaware of it.

Edit: Appologies for the spam. As I mentioned, the code itself executes flawlessly in the IDE. There's something going on with the windows task scheduler. Thats preventing the final email from being sent.

Comment: I would use the SQL Server Agent rather than Windows Task Scheduler.